# JPA EnumType.STRING -- issue with bad key values

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm building a Spring data layer to work with a legacy database. The feature of annotating some fields with @Enumerated is new to, but quite useful for the schema I'm working with, where there are scores of reference data tables defining everything from countries to system codes. Most of these tables are very regular in construction. They have a key field, a name, and a description. However, occasionally the key field is not a valid Java identifier. Because of that I can't use @Enumerated with the type EnumType.STRING. This seems to be an oddly intractable problem. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: When do you get such an error? Any error stack or flow would help?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm not explaining the problem clearly. OK, the annotation: @Enumeration(EnumType.STRING) lets you use a Java enum in an Entity instead of joining in a data table, right? When you store that entity, the enum's name() method is called, and the result stored in the db table for that field. The assumption is that you will only need to store strings that are valid identifiers for a Java enum. That's an odd assumption, and I can't figure a way to work around it. The error comes at compile time if I need to store something with a key of, for example, "1_DAY_AT_A_TIME".

Comment: That's what enum's are used for, to tighly bind your variables to a set of constants. As long as you are assigning something under the scope of an enum things should work.

Comment: True, but in this case I'm using enums to map to a database string field, and there's nothing that forces the database string to be a valid Java identifier.  I think that's a ridiculous oversight in the @Enumerated support of Java Persistence. Why not use the toString() or a user-defined method of the enum? Why does it have to be name()? If there's not a workaround now, then I'm sure it will be fixed eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the answer is to use an AttributeConverter, which has an additional advantage that entities that use it don't have to annotate the field as an enum. Full code example follows:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

public enum RefExample {

  GOOD_VALUE("Data good key value", "The key for this record is GOOD_VALUE, a valid Java identifier"),
  _1_DAY_AT_A_TIME("Data with bad key value", "The key for this record is not a valid Java id", "1_DAY_AT_A_TIME");

  private final String name;
  private final String description;
  private final String dbString;

  RefExample(String name, String description) {
      this(name, description, null);
  }

  RefExample(String name, String description, String dbString) {
      this.name = name;
      this.description = description;
      this.dbString = dbString;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
      return description;
  }

  public String toDbString() {
      return dbString == null ? name() : dbString;
  }

  public static RefExample fromDbString(String dbString) {
      for (RefExample value : values()) {
          if (value.toDbString().equalsIgnoreCase(dbString)) {
              return value;
          }
      }

      return null;
  }

  @Converter(autoApply = true)
  public static class RefExampleConverter implements AttributeConverter<RefExample, String> {
      @Override
      public String convertToDatabaseColumn(RefExample code) {
          return code.toDbString();
      }

      @Override
      public RefExample convertToEntityAttribute(String dbString) {
          return fromDbString(dbString);
      }
  }
}
```